# hook_views_pre_execute() query not running (or being overwritten)

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I'm trying to completely overwrite the query that's created by Views UI by using `hook_views_pre_execute()` in a custom module. I know about the new database API and how this function expects a SelectQuery object, but I've also read (in a posting from Lullabot, so I think it's legit) that if you're just writing a single query and don't need to do anything conditional, it's perfectly OK to skip that and just use `db_query()` with raw SQL.

So here's my function - the `drupal_set_message()` line is executing, but the output of the view is still sorted in ascending order, which is what is set in the Views UI. My understanding was that this function was supposed to completely overwrite what's in the UI, so how do I get it to work? (Right now I haven't done anything funky with the SQL except change the order by just to see if it would work. There really is other stuff that needs to be done which justifies using a module instead of the Views UI.)

```
function group_speaker_carousel_views_pre_execute(&$view){
    if ($view->name == 'speakers_carousel')  {
      drupal_set_message("view is {$view->name}");
       db_query("SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, field_speaker_node.title AS field_speaker_node_title, field_speaker_node.nid AS field_speaker_node_nid,  'node' AS field_data_field_job_title_node_entity_type,  'node' AS field_data_field_company_node_entity_type
      }
FROM {node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_speaker} field_data_field_speaker ON node.nid = field_data_field_speaker.field_speaker_target_id
LEFT JOIN {node} field_speaker_node ON field_data_field_speaker.entity_id = field_speaker_node.nid
WHERE (((node.status =  '1') AND (node.type IN ('speaker'))))
ORDER BY field_speaker_node_title DESC");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason nothing's changing is because you're just *running* `db_query()`, not actually assigning it to anything. If memory serves you need to assign your new query to `$view->build_info['query']` (but that might be for Drupal 6).

Also you won't unfortunately be able to use a vanilla `db_query` for this (as far as I know), because Views is expecting a `db_select()` object.

You can test this pretty easily by running the following two statements:

```
// Breaks the view.
$view->build_info['query'] = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node}');

// Does not break the query (but results are wrong obviously).
$view->build_info['query'] = db_select('node', '')->fields('n', array('nid'));
```

I would look at re-working your query into a dynamic `db_select()` and then assigning it as in the above example, you should get more joy.

Comment: I haven't been able to find much documentation on dynamic db_select queries. The main reason I wanted to use raw SQL is because I really need to use a group_concat, which Drupal doesn't seem to support anywhere.

Comment: [This page](http://drupal.org/node/310075) is probably the best resource. As far as `group_concat` goes you can use `$query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(field)', 'alias');` or similar on a dynamic query. You can inject any SQL expression with that method, and add any WHERE clause with the `where()` method

Comment: Thank you! This is really kind of a pain for a single query that doesn't really need anything dynamic, but I guess it's the only way now.

Comment: No worries :) There might be a way of setting the SQL string directly but I don't know what that is...might be worth asking a general question to that effect, there are some veritable Views gurus on this site

Comment: One more question - when using `$query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(field)', 'alias');` does the field I'm using it on have to already have been added to the query in `$query->fields`, or does the `addExpression` take care of adding the field as well?

Comment: It's taken care of for you...imagine that the `fields()` function is adding `field1, field2, field3` etc after the `SELECT` part of the query, and `addExpression()` is just tacking onto the end of that: `field1, field2, field3, GROUP_CONCAT(field) AS alias`